# Call Javascript function in android webview (Uncaught ReferenceError)

Tags: javascript, android, exception, webview

I am trying to call a javascript function inside a webview. And I keep getting the following error.
[INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught ReferenceError: onOTP is not defined", source:  (1)

Please you ask, this function is only getting called inside the onPageFinished() method of the webview client. I am successfully able to call an Android function from the html but not the other way around.

Any help?

This is my javascript method:

```
function onOTP(otp){
   console.dir("Otp Triggered " + otp);
}
```

This javascript code is inside a separate js file. I thought that might be the issue and added the same code to the html page with a script tag and still the same issue.

And I am calling this inside:

```
@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:onOTP(465601)");
}
```

Can someone please let me know what I am doing wrong in this?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Have you figured out the solution? If you did, do you mind share it?

Comment: The following answer might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43153916/android-web-view-error-i-chromium-infoconsole1-uncaught-referenceerror