# Android Web-view Error I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught ReferenceError:

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I have a web-service In that I have added bar-code reader for android

So with the Help of JavaScript I am calling my bar-code reader from web-view

So for that [I followed this](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2011/10/call-javascript-inside-webview-from.html)

and designed on server side...
I have Given this

**at JavaScript**

```
    function mybarcd() {
           MyApp.mybarcdt();
        }

    function actfromAnd(msg){
           document.getElementById("brcd").value = msg;
       }


    at HTML/PHP

    <div class="data"> 
            <input id="brcd" type="text" value=""/>
            <button type="button" onClick="mybarcd()">SCAN</button>
    </div>
```

**On Android side**
***In webview***

```
    webView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "MyApp");
```

**and new js interface**

```
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void mybarcdt() {

                IntentIntegrator intentIntegrator = new IntentIntegrator(Main_A.this);
                intentIntegrator.setBeepEnabled(true);
                intentIntegrator.setOrientationLocked(true);
                intentIntegrator.setPrompt("Scan Barcode");
                intentIntegrator.initiateScan();
            }



    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (result != null) {
            if (result.getContents() == null) {
                Log.d("ScanActivity", "Cancelled scan");
                Toast.makeText(this, "Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } else {

                Log.d("ScanActivity", "Scanned");

                String bcval = result.getContents();
                if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) {
                    webView.loadUrl("javascript:actfromAnd(\""+bcval+"\")");
                }else{
                    webView.evaluateJavascript("javascript:actfromAnd(\""+bcval+"\")", null);
                }
                System.out.println("javascript:actfromAnd(\""+bcval+"\")");

            }
        } else
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

My Problem is that Its working fine in a single Html/PHP file with Js on same page or separate page I have tested its scanning and Updating the value in input box...

But its not working since I have using multiple pages or frame in one webview...
its missing JS value... How ever form server its opening scanner at on-click... but after scanning the value is not passing to the input box with JS I am getting this error.....

```
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught ReferenceError: actfromAnd is not defined", source:  (1)
```

**Update**

1)I hava Tried this in Static Page with JS in side that PHP/HTML page
2)I also tried with same in a static Page with JS seperate page
On the above two conditions its worked fine

But In my web-service I have Given Same JS file which is running successfully in Static page I have a single JS file for My Webservice and Static page its working fine in static but not working in MY webservice live.. How ever JS is loading Because on click its wokring from that JS and its opening Camera
But responce after scanning its not going to web input

I understand that I am getting Error Because...

> In my Live Page I have a MainMenu Inside that menu when I select a application its loading in `iframe` So my Android Activity responce after scanning Is pinging to that Mainmenu page But for menu there is no Js  function named `actfromAnd` So I am getting Error...

Here I can't give URL of that particular page(`iframe`) Because of depending on the menus it will change I can Give Only Login or MainMenu link directly.but not for  a particular page inside the menu

Can Any one suggest me on this kind...

Comment: where is the actfromAnd method written? If it's in php is the script written to the output page?

Comment: `actfromAnd` is written in JS and Android Both Form android I will send my bar-code output to `actfromAndroid` with JS but How ever its working but ... Its not working in my case please check my update question... Because of `iframe` is not responding... My application is sending data to menu page not `iframe page` So I am getting error

Comment: try with parent.<<yourfunction>> name if you used iframe

Comment: What is introducing in the `iframe` in there?

Comment: Thanks @bluehipy .... My web-service with button is present in Iframe .... In my web-service Menu I have a lot of Modules So when I click on them they will Load in a I iframe So I that I frame Js is there So when I click on there its opening Android activity out side the web-view but after scan I am passing data to same site But Instead of iframe its passing value to main Menu...

Comment: Thanks @DamodharMeshram .... Can You suggest me clearly what is .... try with parent If possible can you answer I am not Understanding it....

Comment: if we loading the page in an iframe and we need to call parent function in that time we need add parent before calling parent <<function>>.

Comment: @DamodharMeshram can you answer it... I am not getting.. In android or in webservice

Comment: Show us the source you load in the webView. My guess is the javascript you describe is loaded in another document than the one you are trying to evaluate the `javascript:code`. We have to understand the structure of your `dom` to be able to advice.

Comment: I have  a Main menu without JS on it .. in When I select any Application It will Load in `iframe` where as menu remains same... its a tree menu .. But when I send value form activity to web-view with JS its checking for JS in main menu not in `Iframe`.. SO i am getting error.. Can any one suggest me how to send the value to `iframe`... Because my app is checking for url only.. not frame

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this script in Web-service at your Parent Menu which has your `iframe` or `iframes`

```
<script>
function actfromAnd(msg){
window.frames['yourExactframe'].document.getElementById("brcd").value = msg;
}
</script>
```

If you are using same in more than one frame then declare your frame name globally

I tried your Code Working Fine... In my example Frame Hope It works fine for you

Nice question....

Comment: Thanks This sample Code helped me.... **`window.frames['yourExactframe'].`** Its worked... Just one line....

Answer (score 2):

- You should execute the javascript when the page is loaded

  `mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
      @Override
      public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            webview.loadUrl("javascript:myFunction()");
      } 
  });`
- The code will be executed and will find your javascript function. The way you are doing now does not wait.

Comment: Thanks for response user@Harshil Kulkarni....... I have added this in onPageFinished But No response still same issue... Because After Login I need select menus after that In a menu My web-service is there for that particular module only have this Java script... So Its not working...

Comment: OK, sorry for this, i will delete my post later.

Comment: No prob.. But this may help some one so keep answer if you get new Make a Update it.... Thanks...

Comment: Sure why not @MLN.

Answer (score 0):

Just a little bit note; if you are getting `I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(2)] "ERR [object Object]", source: http://...js` error, please check your link security. Because android may not want to run all javascript functions incoming not secure websites.

Most of time, you should not use not secure urls in android anymore.

For example;

http://example.com  --> nonsecure url, you should not use this in WebView

https://example.com --> mostly secure url, you may try to use this in WebView